# Creating interceptors using Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I love Spring. But when it comes to inserting codes before and after a method execution, I have to admit, Spring/AOP's got it wrong.

In my humble opinion, hard coding a method name or a regular expression that resembles a method name should be the last thing we ever put ourselves through. We've all learned it the hard way from the XML hell in early 2000s.

In contrast, EJB3's interceptors is annotation based, simple, easier to read and it's more than capable of tackling most if not all of our problems. Wouldn't it be nice if we can code an EJB3 style interceptor in Spring?

The best solution I know of is to use `@annotation` in the pointcut expression, as I've done in the following codes:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AroundExecution {

}

@Component
public class SimpleBean {
    @AroundExecution
    public void printGreetings(){
        logger.info("Hello World 2");
    }
}

@Aspect
@Component
public class SimpleAdvice {
    @Around("@annotation(com.myinterceptors.springaop.AroundExecution)")
    public Object adviceAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object retVal = null;
        try {
            logger.info("Before executing");
            retVal = joinPoint.proceed();
            logger.info("After executing");
        } 
        catch(Throwable e) {
            logger.error("Execution error");
            throw e;
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

It seems it's impossible to eliminate that last bit of hard-coding of the annotation class name.

If I was using Guice, I could do something like this:

```
    public class SimpleModule extends AbstractModule {
        protected void configure() {
        AroundInterceptor interceptor = new AroundInterceptor();
        bindInterceptor(
            Matchers.any(), 
            Matchers.annotatedWith(BeforeExecution.class).or(Matchers.annotatedWith(AfterExecution.class)), 
            interceptor
        );
        }
    }

public class AroundInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AroundInterceptor.class);

    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {

        try{
            if(invocation.getMethod().getAnnotation(BeforeExecution.class)!=null){
                invokeBefore(invocation);
            }
            return invocation.proceed();
        }
        finally{
            if(invocation.getMethod().getAnnotation(AfterExecution.class)!=null){
                invokeAfter(invocation);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void invokeBefore(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        logger.info("Intercepted before executing: "+invocation.getMethod().getName());
    }


    protected void invokeAfter(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        logger.info("Intercepted after executing: "+invocation.getThis().getClass().getName()+"."+
                invocation.getMethod().getName());
    }
}
```

Not exactly the prettiest, but it gets the job done.

Decorators pattern is an alternative, but it adds a lot of overhead in maintenance:

[JSR-299 CDI Decorators for Spring beans](http://niklasschlimm.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/jsr-299-cdi-decorators-for-spring-beans.html)

It'd be much easier if Spring can allow augmentation to the pointcut expression to support class definition as parameters e.g. `@Around("@annotatedWith", MyAnnotation.class)`

I wonder if anyone has ever implemented interceptors in Spring that doesn't require hard coding in metadata or application context?

Comment: And how is your code not hardcoded? You cannot change it on the fly, either way requires a full recompile. Also note that it isn't Spring AOP but AspectJ (Spring AOP can leverage AspectJ or not depending on what and how you want to use Spring AOP). I actually dislike the EJB (or actually CDI interceptors but that is IMHO).

Comment: I wrote "It seems it's impossible to eliminate that last bit of hard-coding of the annotation class name", which is a reference to this section of the code: "@annotation(com.myinterceptors.springaop.AroundExecution)". We're "hard-coding" a class name in a string literal. What if the class name changes but this string literal does not? It's a matter of personal taste whether it's acceptable to rely on something other than the compiler to pick up that mismatch but I'd personally prefer a solution that involves the compiler.

Comment: And as I stated that is because you choose to use the AspectJ approach. If you wouldn't use that you can do whatever you want. If you instead use plain Spring AOP you can use an `AnnotationMatchingPointcut` which if you configure that with Java based config gives you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit late but look at this code in the official Spring documentation :

```
@Before("com.xyz.lib.Pointcuts.anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(auditable)")
public void audit(Auditable auditable) {
    AuditCode code = auditable.value();
    // ...
}
```

notice the **auditable** argument name which is referenced in the pointcut.

If you want to use @Around advice just modify your code like this :

```
@Around("com.xyz.lib.Pointcuts.anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(auditable)")
public void audit(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Auditable auditable) {
    AuditCode code = auditable.value();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Once again, the string literal must match the class name. If I misspell it as "audible", the compiler would have no problems with it, but it would certainly fail in run time. And again, it's a matter of personal taste whether it's OK to leave it to IDE or unit tests to pick up the error. I personally believe for a strongly-typed, compiled language like Java, we should strive for a solution that turns such an error into a compile time error.